# Run Test of Geb Spock JUnit without starting the application

Tags: java, grails, groovy, junit, geb

I'm writing JUnit test using Geb in order to test my web application.

The tests don't need the web application on the test server because they connecting to a remote server that the application already running on it.

When running the tests, even one test the framework starting the application server which takes time (especially when debugging).

Is someone knows how to prevent the application from starting when running the tests?

Thanks

I'm using:

org.gebish:geb-spock:1.1.1

org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4

junit:junit:4.12

Comment: It is quite easy to prevent: Don't start it from your own build process. Neither Spock nor Geb start any servers by themselves unless you configure them to do so. Never having used Grails, I do not know if there is some test extension that might do that for you. But if so, I am sure you can deactivate it for non-integration tests. I cannot say anything more concrete as you chose not to share any code or build configuration.

Comment: The docs indicate that grails start the server: "When the test is run the application container will be loaded up in the background and you can send requests to the running application using the Geb API"
https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/testing.html#integrationTesting
Maybe it possible to use applicationClass= with dummy application?

Comment: Why do you start Grails at all if you just want to run unit tests? As I thought, it is a problem with your build settings. Maybe one of the Grails guys around here can tell you what to do without you showing your project, I cannot. Thus, I recommend to share an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and not just a list of three dependencies.